# Loading 1 million records using bulk API: Exceeding batch Limit

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits, bulk-api, apex-flex-queue

Whenever records are inserted in Contacts(usually inserted in 1000's), we have a batch job that checks related customer account in SFDC and populates the contact.accountId field and couple other fields. This so far worked fine.
Now, we have a scenario where 1 million contact records (approximately 5000 batches) should be inserted into SFDC using Bulk API, and even with flex queue enabled, I am running out of available batches.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger conTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
    ContactHandler.managecontacts(trigger.new);
}
```

**ContactHandler.class**

```
public static void managecontacts(List<Contact> acList) {
    Database.executeBatch(new UpdateContactsBatch(acList));
}
```

**UpdateContactsBatch.class**

```
    public class UpdateContactsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
        List<Contact> acList = new List<Contact>();

public UpdateContactsBatch (List<Contact> acList) {
this.acList = acList;
}

            public Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
                return [select id, accountId from contact where Id In: acList];
            }

            public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<AccountContacts__c> scope) {
                ContactTriggerHandler.managecontacts_execute(scope);        
            }

            public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) { }        

        }
```

One option I have is to turn off the trigger during this mass load and manually run the batch from anonymous window after inserting all contacts. (Tested this scenario and this is working fine in PreProd environment). In Production this requires 2 times deployment (one for activating trigger and one for deactivating. Donot prefer having custom settings to control trigger behaviour)

But would like to know if there is any other option to handle this scenario.

Problem: I changed the batch size to 5000 in my dataloader which is currently set to "Use Bulk API" but still seems like my trigger is getting 200 records at a time and for each load of records from trigger.new, a batch job will be queued

[image]

Comment: What is the method of invoking the bulk api?

Comment: I am currently using dataloader for it. In dataloader, settings > check the option "Use Bulk API" and you can define batch size there

Comment: is there an option to set the concurrencyMode?

Comment: added screenshot of settings in dataloder. I dont see concurrency mode there

Comment: Try checking "enable serial mode for bulk api"! Also REDUCE your batch size.  I could be wrong but, if you run 1000 items, it will be split into trigger batches of 200 and you will end up with potentially 5 batches at once. Start small and work your way up.

Comment: If i redice my batch size, it means more batches which I am actually trying to avoid... anyway, I just checked the option you suggested and loaded 300 contacts, but still it is processed in 2 batches when i checked in Apex Jobs

Comment: that makes sense, because a Trigger can never process MORE than 200 at a time.  Thus no matter how big you set the bulk batch size, your Batchable class will only ever receive 200 items from the trigger.  I'm pretty sure the error you are running into is that you have too many Batch Jobs running at once (I think you can only have 5 or 6).  Depending on how long your batches take you run, you still might run into a limit issue, even with the bulk process running in serial as the batches might get behind.

Comment: you can have 5 batch jobs with status = processing at any given time. And with flex queue enabled, you can have additional 100 jobs in holding status so maximum at ay point of time, say 105

Comment: In my case for 1 million records means 5000 batches. lol... So looking to find if anyone faced similar situation. One option is definitely scheduler but interested in knowing from community people if they faced this earlier and solved it

Comment: Oh nice, I haven't used flex queues yet.  Sounds sweet!  I think you might actually be good then.  But... If that doesn't work, the I would just have your trigger mark a field on the contact to indicates it needs to be processed and then just have a single scheduled batch come through and process all contacts that are marked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the problem is that the bulk data API is running multiple asynchronous batches and thus kicking off too many Batchable Contexts.

It looks like your batch process doesn't actually care what Id's you pass in and instead just processes everything?

If this is the case and you don't need real time (or close to realtime) updates, it might be a better idea to just schedule this to run.

Otherwise, if you need it to happen in near real time, you could use [batch "chaining"](http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/10/14/winter13-chaining-batch-jobs-with-great-power/) in order the have the batch keep running as long as there are records to process.

The basic steps would look something like this:

1. In the finish method, add a check to see if there are more records to process.  If so kick off another batch.
2. In your trigger, have it first check if the batch is already running.  If so, you don't need to do anything.  Otherwise, have it kick off the batch.

### Update

If you have access to the JobInfo concurrencyMode param, you can [set this to "Serial"](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Salesforce_Bulk_API_-_Maximizing_Parallelism_and_Throughput_Performance_When_Integrating_or_Loading_Large_Data_Volumes#SerialLoad) and it will prevent multiple batches from running in parallel.  I think this might solve you problem. If that alone doesn't work, try also reducing the batch size. Obviously, this will cause the import to take much (much) longer.

On the dataloader this Serial can be turned on by checking "Enable Serial Mode for Bulk Api".

Comment: Let me correct the code.. I got what you said that I am querying all the ids... Will paste updated code soon

Comment: updated my code.. also, when loading contacts from external source using bulk API, I set the batch size to 5000 instead of 200 but still same error. Will look into chaining and see if it helps